# tsc *.ts --target ES5 why this command Isn't working on cmd

Tags: angular

im trying to use set and get in ts file, but cmd generates this error :

app/like.component.ts:17:5 - error TS1056: Accessors are only available when targeting ECMAScript 5 and higher.

17 get x() // this is the error line

so i searched and found that i need to change the target to es5 to all ts files using this command tsc *.ts --target ES5 
,but *.ts is not working in cmd it gives this error:
error TS6053: File '*.ts' not found.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to need more context to help you. Can you provide a link to a somewhere the error is reproducible?. From what I see here though, are you running the `tsc` command in the same directory your `like.component.ts` is in? You could also change your wildcard to `**/**.ts`.